# Common class/function called from multiple Widget/State

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function which is used from a few widget or State class.

For example like this, It checks the common parameters which are stored in device.

I want to use this function from multiple pages or widget class.

What is the best practice for this??

```
  Future<bool> _getCommonParam() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getBool('param') == null){
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return (prefs.getBool('param'));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use some kind of state management or dependency injection to provide such values accross your app, I personally use https://pub.dev/packages/provider but there are many alternatives including simple InheritedWidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare it in a separate class, as such :

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class AppPrefs {
  static Future<bool> getCommonParam() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getBool('param') ?? true;
  } 
}
```

You can then call `AppPrefs.getCommonParam()` from anywhere as long as you import the class.

*Note : The ?? operator returns the right expression if the left expression is null.*

Answer (score 1):

**Create Class with specific name and function and implement methods to related classes or widgets**

like below example

I created a class with the name of

```
class AppTheme {
      static final primaryFontFaimly = "CerbriSans";

      static Color mainThemeColor() {
        return HexColor("#e62129");
      }

      static TextStyle tabTextStyle() {
      return TextStyle(
        fontFamily: AppTheme.primaryFontFaimly,
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        color: AppTheme.mainThemeColor()
      );
     }
    }
```

and this class I will use in Another class like this

```
                  Text(
                        "Example",
                        style: AppTheme.tabTextStyle(),
                      ),
```

you have to just import library to related this class

**Note: This example only for the ideal purpose/only for idea**

Comment: THank you for your example. static class works for me and example of AppTheme is good help.